# MSBuild Copy task not copying files the first time round

Tags: msbuild

I created a build.proj file which consists of a task to copy files that will be generated after the build is complete. The problem is that these files are not copied the first time round and I have to run msbuild again on the build.proj so that the files can be copied. Please can anyone tell me whats wrong with the following build.proj file:

```
<Configuration Condition="'$(Configuration)' == ''">Debug</Configuration>

<SourcePath Condition="'$(SourcePath)' == ''">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)</SourcePath> 

<BuildDir>$(SourcePath)\build</BuildDir>

</PropertyGroup> 

<ItemGroup> 
    <Projects 
       Include="$(SourcePath)\src\myApp\application.csproj">  
    </Projects> 
</ItemGroup> 

<Target Name="Build">
   <Message text = "Building project" />    
   <MSBuild   
     Projects="@(Projects)" 
     Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)" /> 
</Target>

<ItemGroup>
   <OutputFiles Include ="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\**\**\bin\Debug\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyToBuildFolder">
   <Message text = "Copying build items" />
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(OutputFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(BuildDir)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="All"
   DependsOnTargets="Build; CopyToBuildFolder"/>

</Project>
```

Comment: Fix the indentation of your code please, it's not understandable.

Comment: Sorry had a bit of trouble inserting the script...Everything is sorted now

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The itemgroups are evaluated when the script is parsed. At that time your files aren't there yet. To be able to find the files you'll have to fill the itemgroup from within a target.

```
  <!-- SQL Scripts which are needed for deployment -->
  <Target Name="BeforeCopySqlScripts">
    <CreateItem Include="$(SolutionRoot)\04\**\Databases\**\*.sql">
      <Output ItemName="CopySqlScript" TaskParameter="Include"/>
    </CreateItem>
  </Target>
```

This example creates the ItemGroup named "CopySqlScript" using the expression in the Include attribute.

Edit:

Now I can read your script: add the CreateItem tag within your CopyToBuildFolder target

Comment: NP, it took me a while to figure this out too.

Comment: It's 2014 and I'm still making this mistake! Thanks :)

Comment: I spent an embarrassing amount of time trying to figure out why copy tasks appeared to by asynchronous when really it was my ItemGroup in the wrong place.

Comment: MSBuild 3.5 and up support ItemGroups within Target, no need for CreateItem. Same for PropertyGroups and CreateProperty.

Comment: Also, the MS documentation show an example to recursively copy files, where the same mistake is made: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2022 .
I've logged a ticket to resolve this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/7591

Comment: can you show the completed mark up this is hard to follow, ps i dont think this work for .net core latest

Comment: 2022 this is a thing, thanks @Nullius, i didnt know it had to be inside the Target aka the ItemGroup inside the Target tag, that was one of my issues.